# Does Django Development Web Server Cache Redirects?

Tags: django, django-views

I have a Django view that I redirect a user to after they login:

```
    # settings.py
    from django.urls import reverse_lazy
    ...
    LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('login-redirect')

    # account/urls.py
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
        ...
    ]

    # home/views.py
    from account.models import Member

    def login_redirect(request):
            """
            Redirect member to appropriate page when they log in.
            """
            member = Member.objects.get(user__id__exact=request.user.id)
            if member.has_profile:
                    return redirect('homepage', member_id=member.id)
            else:
                    return redirect('profile-create', member_id=member.id)
```

If I start Django's development server and execute this code when the condition `member.has_profile = True`, Django redirects me to the homepage view as expected.  But if I then go into the database and set has_profile to False, restart the web server, and execute code again, my website acts as if the code isn't executed.  Instead, I'm sent immediately to the homepage view again.  I can see this by looking at the terminal console:

```
[19/Feb/2021 ...] "GET /account/login/ HTTP/1.0" 200 4268       # I'm using Django's default login method
[19/Feb/2021 ...] "POST /account/login HTTP/1.0" 302 0
[19/Feb/2021 ...] "GET /home/login_redirect/ HTTP/1.0" 200 4599
```

This happens even though I am restarting the server and clearing my browser's cache.  In fact, I can edit the login_redirect function so that it only contains a single line `pass` and I'm still sent to the homepage after logging in.

```
    def login_redirect(request):
        pass
```

Why is this happening?  I'm not doing a permanent redirect.  And should I not be using the redirect method in my login_redirect method to send a user to a different page depending on whether or not they have a profile?

Comment: You may be onto something in your last statement. [`HttpResponseRedirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) is the standard for redirections in Django; I've never seen `redirect()` before.

Comment: @NatRiddle redirect is a shortcut function.  All redirects are not permanent by default. 
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Comment: @Ray, By default Django is using `Local-memory caching`. You can use `Dummy caching` or decorator `never_cache`.

Comment: @NatRiddle I made the change you suggested but that did not fix the problem.  For the life of me, I can't see why this is happening.

Answer (score -2):

By default is Django using **`Local-memory caching`**([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#caches))

Django has a [**`Dummy caching`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#dummy-caching-for-development) for development - [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#dummy-caching-for-development):

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',
    }
}
```

You also can use [**`never_cache`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.cache.never_cache) [decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.cache.never_cache) - is a view decorator that adds headers to ensure the response won’t be cached by browsers or other caches.

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

@never_cache
def login_redirect(request):
    ...
```